# array is not correctly generating a nested structure

Tags: javascript

In my recent javascript brutal interview I have given a statement about the recursive data. The statement was hosted on the GitHub. When I saw the statement I feel a headache for two minutes.

**Data:**

```
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    object: "custom",
    url: "/services",
    title: "Services"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    object: "dropdown",
    title: "Products",
    children: [
      {
        id: 3,
        url: "/01",
        title: "01"
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        url: "/02",
        title: "02"
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        url: "/03",
        title: "03"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    object: "page",
    url: "/work",
    title: "Work"
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    object: "page",
    url: "/contact-us",
    title: "Contact Us"
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    object: "page",
    url: "/lpc",
    title: "Lpc",
    children: [
      {
        id: 9,
        object: "page",
        url: "/pc",
        title: "pc",
        children: [
          {
            id: 10,
            object: "page",
            url: "/pop",
            title: "pop",
            children: [
              {
                id: 11,
                object: "page",
                url: "/tree",
                title: "tree"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

and my task is to write an algorithm to convert that data into the following format.

The requirements are:

- Every item contains an `object` property which can contain only three
  values. `page`, `custom` and `dropdown`.
- It is not necessary for the `object` type `page` or `custom` to have `children` property. But object 
  with type `dropdown` is recommended to have `children` property.
- The item which has an `object` type `dropdown` its sub-item could not
  have any `children` or `object` property.

Convert format would be like this:

```
[
  [
    {
      id: 1,
      object: "custom",
      url: "/services",
      title: "Services"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      object: "dropdown",
      title: "Products",
      children: [
        {
          id: 3,
          url: "/01",
          title: "01"
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          url: "/02",
          title: "02"
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          url: "/03",
          title: "03"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      object: "page",
      url: "/work",
      title: "Work"
    },
    {
      id: 7,
      object: "page",
      url: "/contact-us",
      title: "Contact Us"
    },
    {
      id: 8,
      object: "page",
      url: "/lpc",
      title: "Lpc",
      children: [
        {
          id: 9,
          object: "page",
          url: "/pc",
          title: "pc",
          children: [
            {
              id: 10,
              object: "page",
              url: "/pop",
              title: "pop",
              children: [
                {
                  id: 11,
                  object: "page",
                  url: "/tree",
                  title: "tree"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  // Sub-child of the second item list on the seprate array
  [
    {
      id: 3,
      url: "/01",
      title: "01"
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      url: "/02",
      title: "02"
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      url: "/03",
      title: "03"
    }
  ],
  // Sub-child of the fifth array item on the seprate array
  [
    {
      id: 9,
      object: "page",
      url: "/pc",
      title: "pc",
      children: [
        {
          id: 10,
          object: "page",
          url: "/pop",
          title: "pop",
          children: [
            {
              id: 11,
              object: "page",
              url: "/tree",
              title: "tree"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],

  // Sub-sub Child of the fifth array item on the seprate array
  [
    {
      id: 10,
      object: "page",
      url: "/pop",
      title: "pop",
      children: [
        {
          id: 11,
          object: "page",
          url: "/tree",
          title: "tree"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],

  // Sub-sub-sub child of the fifth array item on the seprate array
  [
    {
      id: 11,
      object: "page",
      url: "/tree",
      title: "tree"
    }
  ]
];
```

So, What I understood from that problem is I have to write a **recursive function** which converts the data into that format. The format is that every sub children of the item will be into another separate array it depends upon the children of the root item.

What my propose solution was I will take 2 arrays

- One will hold all the items which don't have any children.
- The second will hold all the items which contain children.
- In the end, merge those array into one gigantic array.

But I was stuck on the iteration of the recursive children and also my solution was not generated output correctly. I will appreciate it if you provide a better solution.

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    object: "custom",
    url: "/services",
    title: "Services"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    object: "dropdown",
    title: "Products",
    children: [
      {
        id: 3,
        url: "/01",
        title: "01"
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        url: "/02",
        title: "02"
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        url: "/03",
        title: "03"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    object: "page",
    url: "/work",
    title: "Work"
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    object: "page",
    url: "/contact-us",
    title: "Contact Us"
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    object: "page",
    url: "/lpc",
    title: "Lpc",
    children: [
      {
        id: 9,
        object: "page",
        url: "/pc",
        title: "pc",
        children: [
          {
            id: 10,
            object: "page",
            url: "/pop",
            title: "pop",
            children: [
              {
                id: 11,
                object: "page",
                url: "/tree",
                title: "tree"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

const arrangeData = data => {
  const temp = [];
  const arrayWithoutChild = [];
  const arrayWithChild = [];

  // ES6 for...of loop for the collection
  for (const item of data) {
    if (
      (item.object === "page" || item.object === "custom") &&
      !item.children
    ) {
      // It means it is an item without children
      temp.push({ ...item });
    }
    // Else-if block => because `object` type with dropdown has a `children` property and children item could not have any `object` and `children` property.
    else if (!item.object && !item.children) {
      // It means it is an item without children
      temp.push({ ...item });
    } else if (
      (item.object === "page" ||
        item.object === "custom" ||
        item.object === "dropdown") &&
      item.children && item.children.length > 0
    ) {
      temp.push({ ...item });
      const recursionArrayReturn = arrangeData(item.children);
      arrayWithChild.push(recursionArrayReturn);
    }
  }
  arrayWithoutChild.push([...temp]);
  return arrayWithoutChild.concat(arrayWithChild);
};

console.log("Format Data : ", arrangeData(data));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is a bit complicated. This can be done simply with array helpers, all the request asks is that you push each array found in any depth into one outer array. The other requirements seem kind of extraneous to me, the important thing is just that if it has a `children` property, the children get pushed to the results and you search them for more nested children.

```js
const data = [ { id: 1, object: "custom", url: "/services", title: "Services" }, { id: 2, object: "dropdown", title: "Products", children: [ { id: 3, url: "/01", title: "01" }, { id: 4, url: "/02", title: "02" }, { id: 5, url: "/03", title: "03" } ] }, { id: 6, object: "page", url: "/work", title: "Work" }, { id: 7, object: "page", url: "/contact-us", title: "Contact Us" }, { id: 8, object: "page", url: "/lpc", title: "Lpc", children: [ { id: 9, object: "page", url: "/pc", title: "pc", children: [ { id: 10, object: "page", url: "/pop", title: "pop", children: [ { id: 11, object: "page", url: "/tree", title: "tree" } ] } ] } ] } ];

const arrangeData = (arr, data) => { //this will be called with each array
  arr.push(data); //push the array, then...
  data.filter(obj => obj.children) //find elements with children
    .forEach(obj => arrangeData(arr, obj.children)); //and call this function on the child arrays
  return arr;
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(arrangeData([],data),null,2));
```